# Replace arbitrarily many nested for-loops with a generator

Tags: python, list, recursion, generator

I have a lists of lists, like this:

```
indices = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1]]
```

Now I want to loop over all of these indices, meaning that I want to go for the combinations `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`, `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]`, ..., in effect the same as

```
for i in indices[0]:
  for j in indices[1]:
    for k in indices[2]:
      ....
```

I know that this will lead to a combinatorical explosion pretty fast, but I know that everything I'll need this for is tractable.

I am simply looking for a general way to write that, and I think one could build a (recursive?) generator for this, but I cannot wrap my head around how that must look like.

If I knew all of the sub-lists had a fixed length, I would generate the product of the lens of the sublist and then get the binary/ternary/decimal/... representation of that number, however both the length of the sub-lists as well as the length of `indices` is variable.

Comment: `itertools.product(*indices)`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations might be good for inspiration